# VMWare Workstation on Windows7, Firewall Issues

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware, firewall, tftp

I have a Ubuntu image running under VMWare Workstation 11.1 on a Windows 7 pro machine. This VM image is there in part to serve some files over TFTP to a number of hosts on a network.

The tftp server on the ubuntu box is controlled with xinetd with the following configuration:

```
service tftp {
socket_type = dgram
protocol = udp
wait = yes
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args = -s /mnt/tftp_files
disable = no
per_source = 11
cps = 100 2
}
```

I've gone into windows firewall (which I cannot disable due to group policy) and added a UDP/69 Accept rule.

However I still can't seem to hit tftpd from another host on the network. I see explicit packet drops in the security event logs.

As a troubleshooting step I put a tftpd server on the windows 7 host system, and when it's running I can connect to it without issue.

My current hypothesis is that the 'stealth' features of windows firewall is the problem here. Possibly because of the way xinted works ( Which I'm pretty ignorant of ).

Comment: update the question with your current virtual network topology.

Comment: I'm not sure how to gather that information in the best way for you.

Comment: I mean how the virtual interfaces are set in vmware workstation if they are bridge Nat or host only they all should be in same type

Answer (score 0):

TFTP uses UDP port 69 only when establishing a transfer, next the actual "data" transfer takes place on a randomly selected UDP port that also has to be "open" in your firewall (mechanism somehow similar to FTP transfers)
You can read about the TFTP protocol here [RFC 1350](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1350.txt)